# Canonical riemannian metric on the cotangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given a riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, is there a canonical induced riemannian metric on the cotangent bundle?

Motivation: See this related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082653/metric-induced-almost-complex-structure-on-cotangent-bundle). Also, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52509/riemannian-metric-of-the-tangent-bundle) looks like it is a canonical metric on $TM$, so would it make sense to map $T^*M$ to $TM$ using $g$ and then take the pullback metric on $T^*M$?

Comment: Your suggestion works - $g$ is a canonical bundle isomorphism (and thus certainly a diffeomorphism) between $TM$ and $T^*M$, so you can just transfer the metric from $TM$.